# Comic or Webcomic with a robot enthusiastically proclaiming "Krill the humans!"

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots, webcomics

I was reading an article recently that mentioned the use of [krill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krill) as a food source, and I found myself remembering a panel where a robot is enthusiastically chanting "Krill the humans!" with the joke being that it seems a bit like the [Killer Robot](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KillerRobot) trope (actually, I'm now wondering if it was a direct reference to the *Dr. Who* episode "[The Robots of Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Robots_of_Death)"), but they were actually enthusing about the idea of gifting krill to humans. It was in a cartoonish art-style. The robot was humanoid, and might have had [red eyes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RedEyesTakeWarning) to further the Killer Robot joke. I don't remember if it was a comic or a webcomic, and I have no firm idea of when I read it, although I think it was at least ten years ago.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the webcomic *[Freefall](http://freefall.purrsia.com/)*. [Panel #2022](http://freefall.purrsia.com/ff2100/fc02022.htm) (dated 2011) has a pink-eyed robot chanting "**Krill all humans! Krill all humans!**"

[image: Strip of Sawtooth attempting to make Bennie the spokesman before changing his mind]

Comment: That looks to be the one. And I'm an avid *Freefall* reader, so it would make sense that I would remember it fondly. I just was using the wrong phrase, I guess...

Comment: Mostly just curious, but what's with the overlays on the original speech bubbles?